# Writting Duplicate Object data to a binary file

Tags: java

I'm going to try to keep it as simple as possible. I have a Program that adds values to the table. When a button is clicked it reads values from the table, creates an object and writes to a binary file(.ser).

When I loop trough the list (e.g. 3 times if i added three object values to the table) of the table, then I create an object and write it to a file. But when I read the same file it just reads the same object ( 3 times if I added 3 objects to the Table). Why is it doing that? I'm new to Java any help would be great thanks

Object Structure

```
public class Empleados implements Serializable {

public int NoEmpleado;
public String ENombre;
public String EApellido;
public String EGrupo;
.
.
Setters and getters 
}
```

Following code runs when I click a button to write to binary file (takes data from a table previously filled with data). I am also closing the file after all of this is done.

```
            try // open file
            {
                outputS = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( "empleados.ser" ) );
            } // end try
            catch ( IOException ioException )
            {
                System.err.println( "Error opening file." );
            } // end catch

            for (int num = 0; num < tableModel2.getRowCount();num++)
            {                                   
                try
                {

                empleado1.setNumero(Integer.parseInt(tableModel2.getValueAt(num, 0).toString()));
                empleado1.setNombre(tableModel2.getValueAt(num, 1).toString());
                empleado1.setApellido(tableModel2.getValueAt(num, 2).toString());
                empleado1.setGrupo(tableModel2.getValueAt(num, 3).toString());

                int n = empleado1.getNumero();

                if (empleado1.getNumero() > 0)
                {                       
                    outputS.writeObject(empleado1);                                                 
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Numero debe ser mayor a 0.");
                }
                }
                .    
                .
                fallow by rest of catch stataments
```

Comment: Also post the reading code, please. At first glance the writing code seems fine. Why don't you create a new instance of the object inside the loop?

Comment: @JPMoresmau excellent suggestion that did it ! Its writing to the file without duplicates !

Comment: Do you mean that all three Empleados are serialized but while deserialization you get only one?

Comment: @Garry At the time of deserialization I was getting the First Empleados object three times. But As JPMoresmau suggested I moved my Instance of Empleados inside the For Loop and now it works like it suppose too !